# Set custom width and height Image in Kendo Editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

Is there any way of setting width and height of images in Kendo Editor?
 How can I set the width & height of the image when uploading in Editor content. How can I write to display width & height (100px) after selecting from image browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of Kendo UI  (v2014.2.716) that's the default behavior. The popup that opens for loading the image already includes fields for saying width and height.

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/zuN45/